# WPF create combo box programatically do not show items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create `DatagridComboBoxColumn` from code behind. How can I properly link it to `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` ?

I'm trying to create this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxElementStyle}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditingElementStyle}" />
```

which creates this:
[image]

from this:

```
private List<AppSettingsElement> appSettingsComboBoxList = new List<AppSettingsElement>();
...
private DataGridComboBoxColumn CreateComboValueColumn()
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    column.ElementStyle = Resources["ComboBoxElementStyle"] as Style;
    column.EditingElementStyle = Resources["ComboBoxEditingElementStyle"] as Style;
    return column;
}

...
AppSettingsDropDowns.ItemsSource = appSettingsComboBoxList;
...
public class AppSettingsElement : ComboItem0
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<ComboItem> ComboItems { get; set; }
}
public class ComboItem
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }    

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Which do not display comboBox:

[image]

Style which I'm trying to link:

```
<!-- ComboBox element and editing style -->
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Value}" />
    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Text"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="ID" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditingElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Value}" />
    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Text"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="ID" />
</Style>
```

Comment: your C# code is missing binding with some property...can you please follow this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71f78c62-8bb5-462a-81d8-db4891b3fe25/populate-dynamic-datagrid-column-and-binding-with-editable-using-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: @VishalPrajapati but I do not bind anything differently when creating columns in .cs file than when creating columns in xamil

Comment: can you try to add this in c# 
column.ItemsSource = ComboItems,ToList() and see if it works in your case

Comment: @VishalPrajapati If I link some ``List<string>`` to itemsource, items are displayed when trying to edit it. But I'm trying to bind custom class. Should I post it here?

Comment: yaa.. sure please post your code freely

Comment: @VishalPrajapati made some edits

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734743/binding-custom-object-to-wpf-combobox

Comment: you have already programmed the line private 
     List<AppSettingsElement> appSettingsComboBoxList = new List<AppSettingsElement>(); for ComboBox itemssource .Same logic is applied for datagridcheckboxcolumn's itemsource as well

Answer (score 1):

First give name to your column like this:
column.Name = "myColumn"

and then try something like this:

```
  List<ComboData> ListData = new List<ComboData>();
  ListData.Add(new ComboData { Id = "1", Value = "One" });
  ListData.Add(new ComboData { Id = "2", Value = "Two" });
  ListData.Add(new ComboData { Id = "3", Value = "Three" });
  ListData.Add(new ComboData { Id = "4", Value = "Four" });
  ListData.Add(new ComboData { Id = "5", Value = "Five" });

 myColumn.ItemsSource = ListData;
 myColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
 myColumn.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
 myColumn.SelectedValue = "2";
```

ComboData looks like:

```
public class ComboData
{ 
 public int Id { get; set; } 
 public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

Now your list is ready and finally in your code apply like this;

```
column.ItemsSource = ListData.ToList();
```